# How to populate a layout depending on which item in a ListView has been selected?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView that is populated with book details from an arrayAdapter and I want know is there any way that I can create **one** layout and have that layout populate depending on which book I have selected?

We have been told to just create individual layouts for each book and then inflate those layouts when the book is selected but if I could, I would rather have just one layout.

Below you can see some images of my layouts.

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivbzO.png)

[Layout that I want to populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQons.png)

I don't know which files of code may be of assistance so I'll show some that will hopefully help.

ProductData.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ProductData {

    private List<Product> products=new ArrayList<Product>();
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }


    public ProductData() {

        products.add(new Product("1984", R.drawable.scifi1, 7.99, "George Orwell"));
        products.add(new Product("Ender's Game", R.drawable.scifi2, 8.99, "Orson Scott Card"));
        products.add(new Product("Fahrenheit 451", R.drawable.scifi3,4.89, "Ray Bradbury"));
        products.add(new Product("Brave New World", R.drawable.scifi4,3.49,"Aldous Huxley"));
        products.add(new Product("Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", R.drawable.scifi5,9.99,"Philip K. Dick"));
        products.add(new Product("Dune", R.drawable.scifi6, 13.81, "Frank Herbert"));

    }

}
```

Product.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Product {
    // constants for field references
    public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";
    public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE = "imageResource";
    public static final String PRICE = "price";
    public static final String DETAILS = "details";
    public static final String AUTHOR = "author";

    // private fields
    private String productName;
    private int imageResource;
    private String details;
    private double price;
    private String author;

    // getters and setters
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }


    // Used when creating the data object
    public Product(String id, int imageResource, double price, String author) {
        this.productName = id;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.price = price;
        this.details = details;
        this.author = author;
    }

    // Create from a bundle
    public Product(Bundle b) {
        if (b != null) {
            this.productName = b.getString(PRODUCT_NAME);
            this.imageResource = b.getInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE);
            this.price = b.getDouble(PRICE);
            this.details = b.getString(DETAILS);
            this.author = b.getString(AUTHOR);
        }
    }

    // Package data for transfer between activities
    public Bundle toBundle() {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(PRODUCT_NAME, this.productName);
        b.putInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE, this.imageResource);
        b.putDouble(PRICE, this.price);
        b.putString(DETAILS, this.details);
        b.putString(AUTHOR, this.author);
        return b;
    }

    // Output product data
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return productName;
    }

}
```

ProductArrayAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class ProductArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Product> objects;

    public ProductArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Product> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Product product=objects.get(position);


        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listitem, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivProductImage);
        image.setImageResource(product.getImageResource());

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
        tv.setText(product.getProductName());

        TextView tvp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
        String priceDouble= Double.toString(product.getPrice());
        tvp.append(priceDouble);

        TextView tva = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductAuthor);
        tva.setText(product.getAuthor());

        return view;
    }



}
```

ProductsFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;


public class ProductsFragment extends ListFragment {

    List<Product> products = new ProductData().getProducts();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ProductArrayAdapter adapter = new ProductArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.product_listitem,
                products);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: i don't get it do you want have another view for the books or just a dialog or what ?

Comment: Sorry, when I click on one of those books I want it to load another layout with an image, title, author, price, summary, etc. and have this layout match the book that has been selected, but instead of creating multiple layouts for each book, I want just one, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are what you are saying is, **you want to inflate another layout when an item in the list is clicked**

You can simply make use of **`OnItemClick`** and then inflate the layout that you want or by simply starting another **`Activity`**.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am after. But I want the new layout that is inflated to be populated by the details of the item that I click. So just 1 new layout to be created and have placeholder image views and text views and then have them load details from an arrayList.

Comment: You can pass on all the details to an `Activity` with `intent.putExtra()` and then in the Activity class you can use `getIntent()` to get your details and place them in the layout of the activity.

Comment: Thanks! it took me a while to mess around with and work out how to use them but I got it working using your help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data make two layouts or as many as you want :

**Below code inside you Adapter :**

```
private final int VIEW_TAG = 0, VIEW_UNTAG = 1;

@Override
public CustomPicker onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TAG:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dialog_tag, parent, false);
            break;
        case VIEW_UNTAG:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dialog_untag, parent, false);
            break;
    }


    return new CustomPicker(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (!tagList.get(position).getTagName().equals("UnTag")) {
        return VIEW_TAG;
    } else {
        return VIEW_UNTAG;
    }
}
```